# How would I convert a c++ vector to a lisp vector in a 0(1) operation

Tags: c++, common-lisp, cffi

I have these C bindings for the C++ `vector<int>` which I have wrapped in CFFI.

I know how to create `vector<int>`s with `std_carrayTovector` and convert the data back to an `int` pointer with `std_vectorToCArray` so that  I can retrieve data from it in Lisp using the CFFI function `MEM-AREF`. I have correct `defcfun`s written for the below.

My question is: How to I convert the output of my `defcfun` for `std_vectorToCArray` into a Lisp vector (eg `#(1 2 3)`) and make it an O(1) operation — i.e. all data copied at the same time.

```
vector_int* std_carrayTovector(int* a, size_t len) {
    vector<int>* v = new vector<int>;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        v->push_back(a[i]);
    return v;
}

int* std_vectorToCArray(vector_int* s) {
    return s->data();
}


(defcfun ("std_vectori_to_carray" %vector-int-to-c-array) :pointer 
  (s (:pointer vector-int)))
```

Comment: If there's copying, it's not `O(1)`.

Comment: So effectively, you're looking for an implementation of vectors in lisp that are backed by C arrays already. If you have to copy the data, it can't be O(1).

Comment: @Ben Voigt Can you give me any help on this issue, pertaining to acomar's advice. Thanks for joining in btw:)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I think the following should work. The important thing that we can use about a `std::vector` is that it's guaranteed to have an honest-to-god array backing. That is, `& my_vector [0]` points at an array of the objects of `my_vector`. (This won't work for e.g. a `std::list` or anything else, of course)

So all you have to do is make a function (in your C++ code) that CFFI can call which returns a pointer to the start of the vector. Presumably something like this:

```
extern "C"
Foo*
start_of_foo_vector (std::vector<Foo> vec)
{
    return & vec[0];
}
```

You'll want an `extern "C"` so you don't need to worry about the name mangling. Of course, you'll have to write a different function for each type (and can't use templates with the `extern "C"`, I don't think).

The pointer you get is valid until you next modify the vector.

Comment: There's actually a simpler a nicer way to get at the underlying data pointer via an actual method on `vector::data()`. I think the OP is looking for a way to take that C array and turn into a lisp type that's backed by the array (for O(1) conversion).

Comment: Wow. I didn't actually know about the `data()` function. D'oh! The OP will still need to write a `start_of_foo_vector` function though because of C++ mangling (or maybe something like swig can help?) But once that's done, the problem is solved: CFFI read from an array if given a pointer to its beginning.

Comment: (er, that was meant to be "CFFI *can* read from an array if given a pointer to its beginning")

Comment: @Rupert Swarbrick Thanks for your help so far, you showed me how to write the  C++ function but can u show me with example code  how i use CFFI read to from the array

Comment: Well, now your question is "How do I read from an external array with CFFI". For that, you want the `mem-aref` function, which takes a pointer, an index and an element type and returns the element at that point in the C array. I don't know how to make a lisp array with the C array as backing.

Comment: @Rupert Swarbrick  I can already read vector elements from the output of std_vectorToCArray(vector_int* s) with mem-aref. What benefit do I get from using your method.  I was hoping to find out how to convert a c++ vector to Lisp vector, but when you said  I don't know how to make a lisp array with the C array as backing. That made me think that is the way you would do it, to make it a 0(1) operation.(new to the idea of a 0(1) op) My intention is, if the c++ vector is [1, 2, 3] the c++ vector should be 0(1) #(1 2 3)..Thanks again for all of your attention to this issue. I do appreciate it:)

Comment: @Rupert Swarbrick   did you see my last comment?

Comment: Ok, well as far as I know you can't do that with CFFI. I had a search in the SBCL user manual to see whether it was possible in an implementation specific way and couldn't work out how. Probably you need to ask on the CFFI mailing list or the mailing list for your implementation. Or just use the pointer explicitly rather than trying to force it to become an array type.